# How to update a map() variable inside a React component, onclick?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, async-await, reload

What is the right way to re-render a `map()` variable without reloading the page? In my **React** application, a button in another component Y needs to run the *map const* in component X all over again, because some of its objects and arrays are changing all the time.

> X.jsx

```
import React, {component} from 'react';
class X extends Component {
   render () {
     return (
          <button>
             reload
          </button>
         )
    }
}
```

> Y.jsx

```
import React, {component} from 'react';
import myjson from './myjson.json';
const myMap = myjson.all.map((all)=>
   <li>
      {all.title}
   </li>
);

class Y extends Component {
   render () {
        return (
           <div>
             {myMap}
           </div>
           )
       }
}
```

> myjson.json

```
{
  "all"[
    {"title": "firsttitle"},
    {"title": "secondtitle"}
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically to re-render , you need to change the state,so react automatically renders your component.In your above code,move your myMap array as a state in Y component and create a handler in Y and pass it as props to X and attach it to the button.

```
import React, {component} from 'react';
import X from 'components/X';// your component path here
class Y extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
     "all"[
     {"title": "firsttitle"},
    {"title": "secondtitle"} ]
     } 
   }
  handlerToUpdateState = ()=>{
   this.setState({...update here.....})
  }
   render () {
        return (
           <div>
             {myMap}
           <X handler={this.handlerToUpdateState}/>
           </div>
           )
   }
}
```